# Extract text from html with substring methods

Tags: html, vb.net, substring

I wanto to extract text from html.
I'm already getting html source with webrequest.

How can I extract text like the following example?:

```
class="btn btn-success btn-lg" href="I wanto to get this link that is changing every time" rel="nofollow noopener">Click</a><
```

Can I do it using substring methods like startwith and end with?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, of course you can do it with the substring method.  Just need to find the indexes of the delimited characters, posslibly the "".  You can use InStr() to find the indexes you need.  Or alternatively a regex to extrack the sting you're after

Comment: Please don't regress to `InStr()`. Although it is perfectly valid in vb.net for backward compatibility, you will be in much better shape to move to C# if you use the .net methods instead of the vb6 methods

Comment: @Hursey for finding indexes .net offers `String.IndexOf`

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Edit your question and add the formatted code.

Comment: @ Mary, yes completely valid and fair comment, mental block on my part

Comment: Guys I found out the solution! But I still need a little help. I'm going to update the question now

Comment: updated. How can I convert those html in string? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So, Using string.indexof I found a solution. I was strugglin a bit with those "" in html string, but this now does what it is supposed to do.

I found the solution!

```
 Dim allinputtext As String = RichTextBox1.Text
    Dim textafter As String = """ rel=""nofollow noopener"
    Dim textbefore As String = "class=""btn btn-success btn-lg"" href="""
    Dim startPosition As Integer = allInputText.IndexOf(textBefore)

    'If text before was not found, return Nothing
    If startPosition < 0 Then

    End If

    'Move the start position to the end of the text before, rather than the beginning.
    startPosition += textBefore.Length

    'Find the first occurrence of text after the desired number
    Dim endPosition As Integer = allInputText.IndexOf(textAfter, startPosition)

    'If text after was not found, return Nothing
    If endPosition < 0 Then

    End If

    'Get the string found at the start and end positions
    Dim textFound As String = allInputText.Substring(startPosition, endPosition - startPosition)
    TextBox4.Text = (textFound)
```